# Auto height in embeded object tag

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to adjust the height automatically to the content of the site that it fetches. I have also tried with iframes. I have read and tried **A LOT** of code examples from here, CSS and JS scripts, but nothing helps.

Thanks in advance Dan.

This is my code.

```
<object type="text/html" data="https://iloapp.learningknots.com/blog/blog?Home#niceURL" style="width:850px; height:2100px;">
<embed src="https://iloapp.learningknots.com/blog/blog?Home#niceURL"></embed>
Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.</object>
```

You can see how it look like on my website here: [my website](https://learningknots.com/news)

Answer (score 0):

Hav a **div** as a container, giv **id**'s.

**HTML**

```
<div class="responsive-object">
  <object id="objid" type="text/html" data="https://iloapp.learningknots.com/blog/blog?Home#niceURL">
    <embed id="thissite" src="https://iloapp.learningknots.com/blog/blog?Home#niceURL"></embed>
    Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.</object>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.responsive-object {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#thissite {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#objid {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Fiddle**

```css
.responsive-object {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#thissite {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#objid {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-object">
  <object id="objid" type="text/html" data="https://iloapp.learningknots.com/blog/blog?Home#niceURL">
    <embed id="thissite" src="https://iloapp.learningknots.com/blog/blog?Home#niceURL"></embed>
    Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.</object>
</div>
```

Comment: Should I still use the style (height:1200px) tag in the objeckt tag?

Comment: Hash, it doesnt work. Sorry. I think.  Could it be, that im using https ??

Comment: snippet works fine for me, _http_ doesnt work me for security reasons.

Comment: Hi agin, I raealy dont know. I still cant get it to work. I have implemented the code, so you can see what it does. [link](https://learningknots.com/news/)

Comment: it doesnt seem like to be in the correct div. u need a left div (next to your right ads div)